# How to setup a mongoDB server and use it for an android application?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, rest, backend

We are developing an android application that needs to communicate with a remote database, in order to sync some Strings. After some research it seems that mongoDB fits all the requirements.

However we are new to back-end and are clueless as to how things actually work. Google wasn't of much help as I couldn't find anything that explains this stuff clearly enough.

From my understanding we need a mongoDB and a REST API server. How do we go about setting these things up to use with android?

A step by step guide and a brief explanation as to what we need would be extremely be helpful.

Comment: I am guessing you are planning to use Node as backend technology?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was considering, and as database the mongodb.

Comment: Then you can follow this tutorial. Or there is more like this on the net. 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB9Fq9I5ocs'

Answer (score 0):

You can go through following link and use step by step.I think it will be helpful.

Click here [A simple CRUD application using Express and MongoDB](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/)